# Bash script: Can't set a variable using which

Tags: linux, bash, shell

In my terminal,

```
prog="cat"
name=$(which $prog)
echo $name
```

prints `/bin/cat`

But in my script:

```
pro="$1"
prog=$(which $pro)
echo "pro is $pro"
echo "prog is "$prog""
```

running `scriptname cat` prints

```
pro is cat
prog is
```

How do I make which work? it should print `prog is /bin/cat`

Comment: Can't reproduce. Does `which` succeed? What happens if you `set -ex`?

Comment: [avoid which](http://stackoverflow.com/a/677212/418413)

Comment: @kojiro what should I use instead to set prog to what I need?

Comment: `prog=$(type -P "$pro")`

Comment: I just created a test script and this worked for me.

Comment: Is there a similar thing to get the full path of a script I created myself?

Comment: Sorry, it turns out it just wasn't working for my own scripts, not bash programs.

Comment: If the command is on your PATH, then `type -P command` will get it. If the command is not on your PATH, then… nope, because how would the system know better than you?

Comment: If you are insistent on using which, add the following line to your script to see what is echoed to the screen. `which $pro`[Not set as a variable] . Cannot reproduce your error but maybe that will help us see what is going on.

Comment: In regards to your question on "is there a similar thing to get full path...", perhaps this link will help.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/can-a-bash-script-tell-what-directory-its-stored-in?lq=1

Comment: I'm not trying to get the path of a script that I'm currently running. It can be any user created script. It seems like it's not possible, since there can be multiple scripts with the same name in different directories.

Comment: Locations you keep scripts in, you can always add to `PATH`

Answer (score 1):

`which(1)` is an external program used to search `PATH` for an executable. It behaves differently on different systems and you can't rely on a useful exit code; use (from most to least portable) `command -v` or `type -P` (to find the path) or `hash` (to check) instead.

try `printf '%s\n' "$PATH"` inside your script as well as outside of it. maybe the command you're looking for is not in the `PATH` used in the script?

That is almost certainly the cause.

Comment: Since `which` can be executed, it means `which` is in the `PATH`. It would be a very odd installation if `cat` would not be in the same directory as `which`, so it should be in the PATH too.

Comment: @user1934428 Specifically speaking about `cat` and alike, you're correct. Thank you for leaving a comment and improving my answer!